# Include @ as key in json

Tags: python, json

Can the @ symbol be utilized as part of writing a Python object to json ? I'm attempting to use :

```
import json

print(json.dumps(dict(@test=test)))
```

expected output is `{"@test":"test"}`

But below error is thrown :

```
File "<ipython-input-38-7b37241c4d92>", line 3
    def __init__(self , @id):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with json. But if you use the `dict()` constructor then the keys have to be valid Python identifiers. If they are not, construct your dict using `{ }`.

Comment: Are you coming from the ruby world? Because in python you can define variables directly..

Comment: Where have you seen that `@whatever` is valid Python syntax for an identifier ??? Also, your traceback doesn't even match your code snippet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(json.dumps({"@test": "test"}))
```

For further explanation see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries